# Inserting factor values into an R matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-factor

I have a matrix of the form

```
arkhansas 15 16 17
newyork 56 45 30
```

where column 1 are factors and columns 2:4 are integers.

I'm stuck trying to generate a matrix with the form:

```
15 arkhansas 1
16 arkhansas 2
17 arkhansas 3
56 newyork 1
45 newyork 2
30 newyork 3
```

Every time I try to assign the factor value to the second column of my new matrix I get numbers instead of city names, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.character()` will coerce your factor into a character string like you want.

That said, providing example code would be helpful.  Try using `dput()` on your matrix object and copying and pasting the results into your post.  You're likely using a data.frame not a matrix, since I believe matrices can only hold one data type.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will do it next time, but thanks!! It worked and now I have the values in the matrix, which I needed to convert to a data frame. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it solved your problem.
For future posts, there's a great guide to allowing others to quickly reproduce your example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
You'll find you get a lot more responses if you make it easy for those who want to help to help.  Good luck on whatever project you were working on!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it! On the same line, another doubt surged: what if lets say I have a value 4.5678 from a data frame and it is a factor, but I want to use it as a number, how do you convert it to respect the entire value?

Comment: I got it: as.numeric(levels(frame$col)[frame$col])

Comment: as.numeric(as.character(my.val)) if I understand your question correctly.